# How do I remove index.php from the URL in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can i remove **index.php** from the URL in Magento.

For example the home page URL is: `www.mydomain.com/index.php`

I want to show : `www.mydomain.com`

So is there any way to do that in the Magento Admin Panel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can remove the index.php in the frontend URLs performing the following steps in Magento's admin section:

In **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations**, select **YES**.

Edit the `/installdir/.htaccess` and uncomment the line:

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

In my case the subdirectory Magento is in is called `magento`, so change it to your subdirectory path if it is different.

Comment: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/how-to-remove-index-php-form-url-in-magento/

Comment: In addition to above make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in your Apache.

Comment: You may find this post useful in case you have existing links including **index.php**  - this prevents all use of the index.php within the site [Removing the index.php from your URL completely](http://secure.nerdster.com.au/knowledgebase/109/Removing-the-indexphp-from-your-URL-completely-.html)

Answer (score 3):

Login to the Magneto Admin portal. Go to **System** >> **Configuration**. Selects the option **Web** from the **General** left tab. Use the option **Yes** for the field **Use Web Server Rewrites** under the tab **Search engines Optimization**

Also check the answer to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234767/my-magento-pages-wont-work-unless-index-php-is-in-url

Answer (score 3):

> **You can remove the index.php in the frontend URLs performing the following steps:**
>
> Go to the admin section of Magento.
>
> 1. In System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations,
>      select YES.
> 2. In System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure -> Use secure URLs in
>      the frontend, select YES.
> 3. Edit the /installdir/apps/magento/htdocs/.htaccess and uncomment the
>      line:
>
>    RewriteBase /magento/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the index.php in the frontend URLs performing the following steps:

Go to the admin section of Magento.

```
In System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations, select YES.
```

Clear cache now see its work. if any case do notwork  go to ftp

find the file in your root .htaccess

check this line it should be comment for example

```
RewriteBase/magento/
```

Replace with this code.

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

Answer (score 1):

EX: Your Site URL is: **http://localhost/my_site/demo1/**

Then add this to (or create) .htaccess (**/my_site/demo1/**.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_site/demo1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my_site/demo1/index.php [L]
```