# Magento Remove index.php from URL

Tags: magento

I have multiple websites installed in one Magento, and for one website, I have a full view store(www.example.com) and mobile view store(www.example.com/mobile). I have taken off the index.php from full store, but for somehow, it cannot be taken off from mobile store, I double checked, (1) Use Web server Rewrites set to yes (2) Use secure Url in frontend to yes (3) .htacess Rewrite Engine on and RewriteBase/. I cleared the Magento cache several times and I even reindexed. Why the index.php is still there?

Here is part of .htacess file.

```
## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
   RewriteBase /
```

Comment: see the code http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/how-to-remove-index-php-form-url-in-magento/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove index.php from the URL in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938860/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-the-url-in-magento)

Answer (score 0):

There are few step to  remove index.php from url

```
Step1:Admin>System > configuration>General>WEb>Search Engine optimization
```

**Use Web Server Rewrites enable to yes**
Also Enable mod_write of apache

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did all of those, but not working.

Comment: How to enable mod-write of apache? Should I contact the webhost?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to remove index.php from URLs in Magento

```
Step 1:
* Goto to your site root folder and you can find the htaccess file there.Open it on text editor and find the line #Rewrite Base/magento.
* Just replace it with Rewrite Base/

Step 2:
* Then goto your admin panel and enable the Rewrites(set yes for Use Web Server Rewrites).
* You can find it at System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization.

Step 3:
* Then goto Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.
```

Comment: delete cache folder from the var.and from your backend go to system->cache mangment flush the cache.my solution should work i had used many times.

Comment: Cleared cached and flushed cache from Magento, still not working.... it is so wired..

Answer (score 0):

Try the Steps I have written in this blog post :

http://magentowebmaster.blogspot.in/2013/11/magento-admin-url-rewrite-set.html