# removing index.php using htaccess prolem in magento

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have tried various option on my local wamp server for magento to remove index.php usng `.htaccess`
as per this stackoverflow link - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls)

I have tried various alternatives like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
## RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
## RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
## RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- I have set the secure url to use on Frontend.
- Also set the Use Web
- Server Rewrites to yes. Cleared all the cache.

Now when I access a category, the url is shown without index.php. But then instead of the showing the category page I get the wamp server configuration page.

> Note: If I insert the `index.php` between the domain and category the
>   page opens correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove index.php from the URL in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938860/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-the-url-in-magento)

Comment: when I told that there is no answer, rather I have given the link to answer myself. What I am asking is even after following the answer I am not getting the intended result.